# get average image in EigenObjectRecognizer?

Tags: c#, opencv

after we get the input image and try to compare with the dataset image 
it is possible to get the average for each image in the dataset when we try to recognize 
the image ?

```
recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
    store_train_image.ToArray(),
    store_names_train.ToArray(),
    3000,
    ref termCrit);

name = recognizer.Recognize(image_result_web);
recognizer.AverageImage  // ????? this point ?
```

Comment: probably only doable from the c++ api. `Mat mean = recognizer.get("mean");`

Comment: no bloody idea. i'm just trying to hint you, at what to search for.